# Suggestion on input length must be multiple of 16 when decrypting with padded cipher

Tags: java, encryption, cryptography, client-server, aes

i m working on java client server aes encryption which server encrypt and client decrypt.However i having the padding error maybe for the byte[] and string..i cant solve it..anyone can tell me what to change to solve the encryption and decryption problem?

SERVER

```
    public void run(){
    try {
        String key1 = "1234567812345678"; 
        byte[] key2 = key1.getBytes();
        SecretKeySpec secret = new SecretKeySpec(key2, "AES");
        String msg = "Singapore Malaysia Japan India";
        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/ECB/PKCS5Padding");        
        cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, secret);
        byte[] encrypted = cipher.doFinal(msg.getBytes());

        in = new DataInputStream(incoming.getInputStream());
        out = new DataOutputStream(incoming.getOutputStream());


        boolean done = false;
        String str="";
        out.writeUTF("Connected!\n");
        out.flush();
        while (!done){
            out.writeUTF(">");
            out.flush();
            str = in.readUTF();
            System.out.println(in+":"+str);
            if (str == null)
                done = true;
            else{
                System.out.println("Sending Ciphertext : " + new String(encrypted));
                out.writeUTF(new String(encrypted));
                out.flush();
```

CLIENT

```
String str = "";
    String str2 = "";
    DataOutputStream out;
    DataInputStream in;

    try {
        Socket t = new Socket("127.0.0.1", 9003);
        in = new DataInputStream(t.getInputStream());
        out = new DataOutputStream(t.getOutputStream());
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader (new InputStreamReader(System.in));

        boolean more = true;
        System.out.println(in.readUTF());   

        while (more) {
            str = in.readUTF();
            System.out.print(str);
            str2 = br.readLine();
            out.writeUTF(str2);
            out.flush();
            str = in.readUTF();

            System.out.println("Encrypted Info: " + str);

            try {
                String key1 = "1234567812345678"; 
                byte[] key2 = key1.getBytes();
                SecretKeySpec secret = new SecretKeySpec(key2, "AES");

                Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/ECB/PKCS5Padding");        

                cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, secret);
                byte[] decrypted = cipher.doFinal(str.getBytes());
                System.out.println("Decrypted Info: " + new String(decrypted));

            }
```

Comment: you had posted the same question before and it was removed by the time I was about to comment. Your logic looks proper however can you check at the server if the new String(encrypted) and the str in the client side are they both the same by logging them. Want to see if any data is lost while you are writing to and reading from DataOutputStream through socket

Comment: Please do not use stackoverflow as your private debugging service. These kind of questions - basically what is wrong? - are not going to be of help to anybody else. Narrow the problem space down first; you would get the same error without the client / sever.

Answer (score 2):

All strings can be converted to bytes, but that is not necessarily the case for the opposite; bytes are not always valid strings.

So what you need to do is to transfer the ciphertext in binary, or you need to specifically encode your bytes to characters using e.g. base 64 encoding.